# how to use yadcf with DataTables deferRender: true

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am on DataTable 1.10.11 and yadcf 0.8.9 and using ajax data source.  yadcf is working great however the column select filters are not populating with all possible results if I enable deferRender.  If I set this to false all possible results appear in the column select filter.  Could someone share with me how to get all possible results for the column select filters while using deferRender?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  BTW I am new to coding so if I did not explain something clearly please let me know.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
var table = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    deferRender: true,
    iDisplayLength: 5,
    aaSorting: [[9,'desc'], [3,'asc'], [4,'asc']],
    ajax:{url:"./assets/json/" + xFileName + ".json"},
    columns: [
        { "data": "col0" },
        { "data": "col1" },
        { "data": "col2" },
        { "data": "col3" },
        { "data": "col4" },
        { "data": "col5" },
        { "data": "col6" },
        { "data": "col7" },
        { "data": "col8" },
        { "data": "col9" },
        { "data": "col10" },
        { "data": "col11" },
        { "data": "col12" },
        { "data": "col13" }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            "targets": [ 0,1,10,11,12 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ],

    sDom: "<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-12'i><'col-lg-12 center'Bp>>",
    sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
    oLanguage: {sLengthMenu: "_MENU_ records per page"},
    buttons: ['excelHtml5', ]        

});

yadcf.init(table, [
    {column_number : 2},
    {column_number : 3},
    {column_number : 4},
    {column_number : 6},
    {column_number : 7},
    {column_number : 8},
    {column_number : 13}],
    {cumulative_filtering: true});
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a test case (simplified is better), also try without `cumulative_filtering`

Comment: I will try and set up a test case when I get a chance.  I've had to work on a couple other projects so it might be a bit before I can return to this.  thanks for you comments.

Comment: So I was able to accomplish what I needed using DataTable's built-in functionality and column filters.  Thanks for trying tho!