# Toggle cumulative_filtering: true/false or similar functionality using deferRender: true

Tags: datatables-1.10, yadcf

I started using yadcf and it works fine for my needs except for one thing, since I have quite a lot of rows for the datatable I use deferRender: true to speed things up. I would like to use yadcf with cumulative_filtering: true but since deferRender is set then the filters will only populate with what's being displayed on the current page.

So if the page length is 50 out of 200 unique rows the filter dropdowns will only contain the 50 rows and not 200 like I would want. This of course works if I set cumulative_filtering: false but then the results will not narrow down when filtering.

Same question was asked here with no real answer,
[how to use yadcf with DataTables deferRender: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107672/how-to-use-yadcf-with-datatables-deferrender-true)

Comment: consider sharing your code

Comment: Ok, here's a test sample I set up that describes the issue.
http://live.datatables.net/ciwijalu/5/edit


Using cumulative_filtering: true and deferRender:true the dropdown at the top will only contain 1 item instead of 3 as the code looks for visible table rows only. Setting deferRender:false will show all 3 rows but I need it set as the data is some 3000+ rows in my real application.